# Which problems in computational geometry or graph theory are believed to be $\Omega(n^3)$?

Tags: graph-theory, cg.comp-geom, lower-bounds

This is intended as a follow up question to Robin Kothari's previous post on [polynomial time hardness results](https://cstheory.stackexchange.com/questions/1284/problems-that-can-be-used-to-show-polynomial-time-hardness-results).

Specifically, I'm interested in seeing some hardness proofs for problems that are believed to have roughly $\Omega(n^3)$ lower bounds, and I say roughly to allow for slightly subcubic improvements by playing with the word size (such as that for 3SUM by Barab et al. [[via Springer]](https://doi.org/10.1007/11534273_36)). I would be happy to keep problems in the decision tree model if it simplifies the responses.

From Robin's post, I learned about Jeff Erikson's [paper](http://cjtcs.cs.uchicago.edu/articles/1999/8/cj99-08.pdf) which gives a $\Omega(n^3)$ lower bound for 5SUM (more accurately, he shows that $k$-SUM runs in $\Omega (n^{\lceil k/2 \rceil})$ time in general).

Do papers or other references exist using such reductions to conjecture cubic lower bounds for problems in computational geometry or graph theory?

Comment: Both of these answers were helpful for me, thanks!  Also, Jeff's pointer to Timothy's paper was much appreciated, that is a very nice result.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

I think the paper "[Subcubic Equivalences Between Path, Matrix, and Triangle
Problems](http://www.cs.cmu.edu/~ryanw/tria-mmult.pdf)" by V. Vassilevska Williams and R. Williams is what you're looking for. Its abstract contains the list of the following problems on graphs:

- The all-pairs shortest paths problem on weighted digraphs (APSP).
- Detecting if a weighted graph has a triangle of negative total edge weight.
- Listing up to $n^{2.99}$ negative triangles in an edge-weighted graph.
- The replacement paths problem on weighted digraphs.
- Finding the second shortest simple path between two nodes in a weighted digraph.

According to the abstract the paper is about the following:

> We define a notion of subcubic reducibility, and show that many important problems on graphs and matrices solvable
>   in $O(n^3)$ time are equivalent under subcubic reductions.

Comment: But see also Timothy Chan's subcubic APSP algorithm, which does NOT play bit games: http://www.springerlink.com/content/px2741688g4p4l18/

Answer (score 9):

One can then use reductions to these problem as starting point to prove lower bounds. See for example section 5 in the following paper: http://valis.cs.uiuc.edu/~sariel/papers/03/lms/lms.pdf. Also section 4 and 5 in the following paper: http://valis.cs.uiuc.edu/~sariel/papers/08/expand_cover/expand_cover.pdf. I am sure there are other examples - this is just papers I worked on and such remember they use such argumentation.

For example, the above prove that given a set of weighted half-spaces in $\Re^5$, finding the minimum weight cover of $\Re^5$ by these half-space requires $\Omega(n^5)$ time.